# Django receive POST from webhook

Tags: python, django

Our App is receiving webhooks via POST from our payment processor. When I was building this function I originally had it to GET for testing purposes so I could use the URL to test paramaters. Everything worked fine but now I need to test with fake purchases which sends POST request to our URL. So I updated the code but no new webhooks are being saved in our database now.

views.py

```
@require_POST
def webhook(request):
    template_name = 'payment/index.html'

    hook = Webhook()
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('clientAccnum', ''))

    hook.user = user
    hook.clientSubacc = request.POST.get('clientSubacc', '')
    hook.eventType = request.POST.get('eventType')
    hook.eventGroupType = request.POST.get('eventGroupType', '')
    hook.subscriptionId = request.POST.get('subscriptionId', '')

    hook.timestamp = request.POST.get('timestamp', '')
    hook.timestamplocal = timezone.now()

    hook.save()

    hook.user.profile.account_paid = hook.eventType == 'RenewalSuccess'
    hook.user.profile.save()

    return render(request, template_name)
```

models.py

```
class Webhook(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    clientSubacc = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    eventType = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    eventGroupType = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    subscriptionId = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    timestamplocal = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I'm firing POST requests now from our payment processor and their support is telling me webhooks are being fired but nothing new is saving in the db. This leads me to believe the views.py code is wrong.

Anyway I can test this?

Comment: Have you tried a simple print to ensure you're entering the function and tried to print `request.POST` to see what's in there? Also - you might want to look at using a `ModelForm` instead of manually handling `request.POST`...

Comment: You almost certainly need to disable CSRF protection on this view.

Comment: It was working with GET and I was printing the webhook details on localhost but get to push all code to the test.domain.com site to receive the POST webhook so it's harder to debug. Everything was working before when I was testing locally with GET.

Comment: try using the decorator @csrf_exempt (from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt)